# Prime number factorisation of power two based numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ two prime numbers and $m$ an integer; does the equation $2^m+1=pq$ admit any solution $(m,p,q)$

Thanks
MTIBAA Riadh

Comment: $2^m$ is already the prime factorisation as $2$ is prime.

Comment: Um... seriously?  If $pq =2^m$ and the the prime factors are 2 so p=q=2 and m =2.  Did you seriously not get that?

Comment: Please add more details, so like that you could get an awesome answer.

Comment: $2^3 + 1 = 3*3; 2^5+1=3*11; 2^6+1=5*13;2^7+1 = 3*43$

Answer (score 2):

If $p,q$ are prime and $2^m=pq$ then $2$ is the only prime factor of $2^m$ so $p=q=2$ and $pq =2^2$ so $m =2$.

Comment: Dear all, I apologize sincerely, actually I missed the unity as shown in the rectification above, so actually I target the equation $2^m+1=pq$. Thank you again

Comment: _Any_ solution is trivial, e.g. the simplest one will be m=3. Did you really have that in mind? If not, then please reformulate your question.

Comment: Dear members, actually I target large numbers covering 512 bits in binary representation  for instance.

Comment: " actually I target large numbers covering 512 bits in binary representation for instance"  ... then this has been one of the most indirect, round-about, and poorly stated posts ever.